# mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: python

I get and error while running with on python:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
You can check the image above

[image]

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: please post the query also